# combine columns within a file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, files, file-format

I need to make some formatting adjustments to some data and I am not sure if there is a simple way to make the changes. I need to combine two columns of data into one column with a "/" in between the two data point.

Input

```
Known Mother    
5 babies                                                                                                                                    
3 Loci                                                               
Mom             314     322     249     261     342     346                 
2_1_2011        314     314     249     257     342     346        
2_17_2011       314     314     257     261     346     346        
2_26_2011       314     314     257     261     342     346   
2_30_2011       314     314     257     261     342     342   
2_5_2011        314     314     249     257     342     342
```

Desired Output

```
Known Mother    
5 babies                                                                                                                                    
3 Loci                                                               
Mom             314/322     249/261     342/346                  
2_1_2011        314/314     249/257     342/346        
2_17_2011       314/314     257/261     346/346        
2_26_2011       314/314     257/261     342/346   
2_30_2011       314/314     257/261     342/342   
2_5_2011        314/314     249/257     342/342
```

The files contain more data then what is shown in the example above and there are 144 files. Any suggestions on how to make the above modifications without manually making the edits in excel would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this problem:

- Identify which lines need to be transformed the way you described: for example, "the lines with 7 columns"
- Perform the transformation

Here's one way to do this using Awk:

```
awk 'NF == 7 { print $1, $2 "/" $3, $4 "/" $5, $6 "/" $7 }
     NF != 7 { print }' input.txt
```

Outputs:

```
Known Mother
5 babies
3 Loci
Mom 314/322 249/261 342/346
2_1_2011 314/314 249/257 342/346
2_17_2011 314/314 257/261 346/346
2_26_2011 314/314 257/261 342/346
2_30_2011 314/314 257/261 342/342
2_5_2011 314/314 249/257 342/342
```

Comment: Maybe more idiomatic: `awk '(NF==7){print $1, $2 "/" $3, $4 "/" $5, $6 "/" $7;next}1' infile`

Answer (score 0):

Unified **`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR<4;
     NR>3{ 
         printf "%s\t",$1; 
         for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) printf "%s/%s%s", $i, $(i+1), (NF-i==1? "":"\t");
         print "" 
     }' file
```

The output:

```
Known Mother
5 babies
3 Loci
Mom 314/322 249/261 342/346
2_1_2011    314/314 249/257 342/346
2_17_2011   314/314 257/261 346/346
2_26_2011   314/314 257/261 342/346
2_30_2011   314/314 257/261 342/342
2_5_2011    314/314 249/257 342/342
```